# Не подключается шрифт к SVG фигуре

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Прописываю фигуру через img путь к svg файлу. В файле прописан стиль и путь шрифта, однако шрифт всё равно остаётся дефолтным. Если прописывать сразу кодом на страницу, то всё работает как нужно.
Вопрос, возможно ли в отдельном svg файле использовать свой шрифт?

```html
<svg id="Группа_1" data-name="Группа 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 156.89 58.89">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c138 79.159824, 2016/09/14-01:09:01        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                           
<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
<defs>
    <style type="text/css">


    @font-face {
        font-family: Exo2; 
        src: url(fonts/Exo2-SemiBold.ttf); 
    }

      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 1.89px;
        filter: url(#filter);
      }

      .cls-2, .cls-3, .cls-4 {
        fill: #fff;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        font-size: 13.731px;
        text-anchor: middle;
        font-family: Exo2;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
    </style>

  </defs>
  <g style="fill: none; filter: url(#filter)">
    <rect id="Прямоугольник_скругл._углы_1" data-name="Прямоугольник, скругл. углы 1" class="cls-1" x="4.945" y="2.945" width="146" height="48" rx="5" ry="5" style="stroke: inherit; filter: none; fill: inherit"/>
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#Прямоугольник_скругл._углы_1" style="stroke: #fff; filter: none; fill: none"/>
  <path id="Фигура_2_копия" data-name="Фигура 2 копия" class="cls-2" d="M536.006,582.421l0.845-1.412,9.143,6.784-0.845,1.411Zm9.143,5.372,0.845,1.411-9.143,6.784-0.845-1.411Zm-1.143-5.372,0.845-1.412,9.143,6.784-0.845,1.411Zm9.143,5.372,0.845,1.411-9.143,6.784-0.845-1.411Z" transform="translate(-418.055 -561.055)"/>
  <rect id="Прямоугольник_2" data-name="Прямоугольник 2" class="cls-3" x="105.945" y="8.945" width="2" height="36"/>
  <text id="Услуги" class="cls-4" style="font-family: 'Exo2'" transform="translate(48.945 33.772) scale(1.165)">  Услуги</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: А где у вас примеры?

Answer (score 2):

Можно дать несколько общих советов, перед конкретным разбором причин неработающего файла?

- Старайтесь не использовать плагин фотошопа для сохранения файлов в
  формате svg.

Так как у него есть возможность присваивать уникальным идентификаторам русские имена, которые могут не работать в svg, что и произошло в вашем случае.
Файл SVG получается очень большим и  неудобным для понимания и редактирования.
Кроме того при сохранении файла происходит дублирование стилей css и команд svg и  человеку, начинающему работать с svg, очень трудно разобраться, почему не работает тот или иной стиль.

- Для создания файлов svg используйте специализированные векторные
  редакторы: <kbd>inkscape</kbd> и <kbd>Adobe Illustrator</kbd>
- Готовый файл svg оптимизируйте утилитами типа - [SVGOMG](https://svgomg.net/)

После прогона в [SVGOMG](https://svgomg.net/), файл теряет в весе несколько раз и становится удобным для чтения и редактирования.

**Влияние внешних и внутренних стилей на стилизацию  шрифтов и другие команды SVG**

- Стилизация текста внутри файла svg может быть выполнена с помощью
  внешней таблицы стилей CSS
- Внутренними правилами CSS в Html страничке.
- Внутренними правилами CSS в SVG файле внутри тегов `<style>..</style>`
- Стилизация внутри команды svg
  `style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; fill:#fff;"`
- а также комбинацией всех вышеперечисленных способов.

*Но наивысший приоритет у последнего способа стилизации.*

Это означает, что если в таблицах CSS будет прописан стиль `fill:#fff`, а в команде svg будет `fill:#000;`, то победит последний стиль.

### Стилизация внутри команды svg

Позиционирование начала текста осуществляется координатами x="10" и y="20"

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 157 59">
  <rect x="5" y="3" width="146" height="48" rx="5" ry="5"  fill="dodgerblue" /> 
 
   <text  class="cls-4" x="10" y="20" style="font-family:Exo2; font-size:15; fill:white">
      Услуги
   </text> 
      <text  class="cls-5" x="50" y="35" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14; fill:orange">
          Налоги
      </text>  
  
           <text  class="cls-6" x="90" y="48" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:10; fill:greenyellow">
              Скидки
          </text> 
  </svg>
```

### Стилизация с помощью правил CSS

```html
<style>
  .cls-4 {
font-family:Exo2;
font-size:16px;
fill:white;

 } 
 
 .cls-5 {
 font-family:Verdana;
 font-size:14px;
 fill:orange
 } 
 
 .cls-6 {
 font-family:Georgia; 
 font-size:10px; 
 fill:greenyellow;
 }
</style>
<svg  viewBox="0 0 157 59" style="border:1px solid grey;">
<rect x="5" y="3" width="146" height="48" rx="5" ry="5"  fill="dodgerblue" /> 
 
  <text  class="cls-4" x="10" y="20">  Услуги </text>  
<text  class="cls-5" x="50" y="35"> Налоги </text>  
 <text  class="cls-6" x="90" y="48" >  Скидки  </text> 
  </svg>
```

### Отредактированный пример от автора вопроса

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 157 59">
   <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      @font-face {
        font-family: Exo2; 
        src: url(fonts/Exo2-SemiBold.ttf); 
    }

      .cls-1 {
        
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        
      }

      .cls-2, .cls-3, .cls-4 {
        fill: #fff;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        font-size: 14px;
        text-anchor: middle;
        font-family: Exo2;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
    
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect  class="cls-1" x="4.9" y="2.9" width="146" height="48" rx="5" ry="5"  />
  
  <path  class="cls-2" d="M536 582.4l0.8-1.4 9.1 6.8-0.8 1.4Zm9.1 5.4 0.8 1.4-9.1 6.8-0.8-1.4Zm-1.1-5.4 0.8-1.4 9.1 6.8-0.8 1.4Zm9.1 5.4 0.8 1.4-9.1 6.8-0.8-1.4Z" transform="translate(-418.055 -561.055)"/>
  <rect  class="cls-3" x="105.9" y="8.9" width="2" height="36"/>
  <text  class="cls-4" transform="translate(48.945 33.772) scale(1.165)" style="font-family:Exo2;">
      Услуги
  </text>
</svg>
```